# How to use hook_node_view?

Tags: nodes, hooks

I'm new to using hooks and I am tryng to use a hook_node_view to my custom module.

Here's my code:

```
function myportfolio_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

$node->content['my_additional_field'][0] = array(
    '#markup' => 'Hello World',
    '#weight' => -1
);

}
```

$view_mode and $langcode appear in gray.

I need to understand... what is this doing exactly? Am I adding a Hello World to all nodes in my site? Because, I need to add it to a node of type "my portfolio" but nothing happens.

What am I missing? Do I need to call this function somewhere in the site? How do I know it is working?

Comment: _$view_mode and $langcode appear in gray._ That's your IDE hinting that you haven't used the vars in the function. You haven't added any conditions, so yes, you're adding that extra field for every node. The hook is invoked from the core `node_view()` function, you don't need to call it yourself. You know it's working if the item you're adding to the content appears on the page

Comment: But it isn't... nothing appears on the page. I created a bacic page "test" and the Hello World should appear on the node... I must be missing something.

Comment: Is the module called "myportfolio", have you enabled it, have you cleared the caches?

Comment: Yes and the module is working. I cleared all the caches... I'm using panels though. Do you think it has something to do with it? Well, I'm not using them in the test basic page... so it shouldn't be that

Comment: I don't really know how panels works under the hood, so yeah, if panels doesn't make use of `node_view` then your `hook_node_view` won't be called. There's no reason why the hook wouldn't fire if the module's enabled, caches have been cleared since the hook was implemented, and `node_view()` is being exectued

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the hook_node_view is not called when using panels, unless you include node_content (add content > node > node content). Once done that, the "No extras" should be unchecked.

Found the solution here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1606912#comment-9009727